# Incorrect date and time when using Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I'm using the plugin [Date Range Picker plugin](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) with some predefined range. The problem is that the "Last 30 minutes" is not showing the correct date range.

**What I expect:**

Say it is  `January 28, 2016 17:00 pm`, When I select last 30 minutes, I expect it to show  `January 28, 2016 16:30 pm` -  `January 28, 2016 17:00 pm`.

**What I got**

`January 28, 2016 12:00 am` - `January 28, 2016 11:59 pm`

The rest of the predefined template seems to work. Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ga073yr6/2/) for you to play.

Comment: Your computer time AND server time need to be set correctly.

Comment: The time is computed client side only and my computer time is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to enable the timePicker Feature like this:

```
$(function() {
      function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY h:mm a') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY h:mm a'));
      }
      cb(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());
      $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
      timePicker: true, /*Add this line*/
        ranges: {
          'Last 30 minutes': [moment().subtract(30, 'minutes'), moment()],
          'Today': [moment(), moment()],
          'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
          'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
          'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
          'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
          'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
      }, cb);
    });
```